# Why does this increase by 2 every time using Array?

Tags: java

Got a litte question for you guys. Trying to teach arrays her, and trying to figur of the way it work etc.
But I got a litle question:

```
int [] array1 = new int[10];

for (int index = 0; index < array1.length; index++) {
            array1[index]++;
            System.out.println(array1[index]);
        }
```

with this for-loop. Why does array increase by 2 for every single element? I mean, I know the answer for this question is: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20 but why does it increase by two for every element?

Why does it not start on 0, and increase by 1 every time?

EDIT:

Bah, thank you guys. I forgot something important before I posted this. I misunderstood.

Before this for-loop i posted I had another for-loop.

```
for (int index = 0; index < array1.length; index++) {
        array1[index] = 2 * index + 1;

    }
```

So I know now why the loop is increasing the way it does. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `Why does it not start on 0, and increase by 1 every time?` why do you believe it doesn't?

Comment: Think your code is wrong.. Output is different from what you said

Answer (score 9):

There's no reason it does increase by 1.

I just tested your code and the ouput was

```
1 1 1 1
```

Because every element is initialized to 0 and then incremented

(Also note I did the initialization. Otherwise no changes)

Answer (score 1):

If I run

```
    int[] array1 = new int[10];

    System.out.println("Before loop: "+Arrays.toString(array1));
    for (int index = 0; index < array1.length; index++) {
        array1[index]++;
        System.out.println(array1[index]);
    }
    System.out.println("After loop: "+Arrays.toString(array1));
```

it prints

```
Before loop: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
After loop: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

> I know the answer for this question is: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20

This suggests you copied the question incorrectly. ;)

Comment: Bah, thank you guys. I forgot something important before I posted this. I misunderstood.

Before this for-loop i posted I had another for-loop.

 for (int index = 0; index < array1.length; index++) {
   array1[index] = 2 * index + 1;
   
  }

So I know now why the loop is increasing the way it does. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
array1[index]++;
```

and it should work.